# Class.superclass = Module, Module.class = Class?

Tags: ruby

How does that compute? It's circular

Update: 
(in irb)

```
Class.superclass = Module
Module.class = Class
```

How is it possible to say that a Module's class is Class, when Class is Modules underclass? It's circular, chicken and egg thing.

Object: same question: Object is the root object in the object model. How can its class be Class, since Class object doesn't even exist yet?

Comment: Or for that matter `Object.class=Class`. ?? Object (the root in Ruby OM)'s class is Class? But Class hasn't even been defined yet?

Comment: This isn't really a well-defined question, but perhaps [this diagram](http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/RubyMethodLookupFlow.png) will help.

Comment: the diagram shows superclasses and eigenclasses. Not of what class is each object in you diagram

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's take a look at the `class.c` file of the MRI source code:

```
void Init_class_hierarchy(void)
{
    id_attached = rb_intern("__attached__");

    rb_cBasicObject = boot_defclass("BasicObject", 0);
    /* boot_defclass is defined as boot_defclass(const char *name, VALUE super) */
    rb_cObject = boot_defclass("Object", rb_cBasicObject);
    rb_cModule = boot_defclass("Module", rb_cObject);
    rb_cClass =  boot_defclass("Class",  rb_cModule);

    /* Very important line: */
    RBASIC(rb_cClass)->klass
          = RBASIC(rb_cModule)->klass
          = RBASIC(rb_cObject)->klass
          = RBASIC(rb_cBasicObject)->klass
          = rb_cClass;
 }
```

These definitions in `ruby.h` are very important, too:

```
#define R_CAST(st)   (struct st*)
#define RBASIC(obj)  (R_CAST(RBasic)(obj))
#define ROBJECT(obj) (R_CAST(RObject)(obj))
#define RCLASS(obj)  (R_CAST(RClass)(obj))
#define RMODULE(obj) RCLASS(obj)
```

Note that `Object`, `Module` and `Class` are derived from `BasicObject`. Indeed,

```
irb(main):001:0> BasicObject.superclass
=> nil
```

Those objects are defined simultaneously and all of them have `RBASIC(*)->klass = rb_cClass`.

Answer (score 3):

`x.superclass` and `x.class` have different semantics. Observe:

```
irb(main):003:0> 3.superclass
NoMethodError: undefined method `superclass' for 3:Fixnum
    from (irb):3
    from :0
irb(main):004:0> 3.class
=> Fixnum
```

`3` doesn't have a `superclass` because... `3` isn't a class or anything like it. But `3.class` means the class that `3` is an instance of.

So the thing that should correspond to `Class.superclass` is not `Module.class`, but `Module` itself.

Answer (score 2):

The circular dependency works because these are all built-in classes. They are part of the core Ruby runtime and are set up this way at start-up and aren't added on the way you would normally add a class. The runtime has the power to set up the pointers however it wants, and the designer chose to do it this way.